# What is the url format for the pages created using spud cms in a grails application?

Tags: grails

I have created a grails site which uses spud cms plugin. Which url format should i use to view the pages that are created using the spud cms.

Note : I am able to view the pages using /spud/admin/pages/ but that is intended for the preview purposes using the administration and hence required to logged in as a admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know what the frontend URLs are? It's just /page-title (dashes instead of spaces and no caps)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Spud page, the name of the page title is converted to the url. This conversion takes out all white space and adds hyphens in their place; it will also take any uppercase letter and make them lower case.

**Example**

```
Page Title:       Frequently Asked Questions
Converts to URL: /frequently-asked-questions
```

In addition you may also create a perma-link for you page via **/spud/admin/pages** to customize the page url. This setting is under **Advanced Settings (optional)**

To add a perma-link click the radio button **Customize this pages url** and input in the input text-box above it your custom url

**Example**

```
support/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions
```

[image]